# Github Workflow correctly loads env with manually triggered job, but not with automated job

Tags: github-actions, environment

My group has a project with a GitHub publishing workflow that has two versions: one which is automated as soon as the builds are finished compiling and one that can be manually triggered from the GitHub Actions interface. Aside from the triggering event, the jobs in the yaml files are identical.

The issue is that in the case of the automated trigger, the env is not being completely loaded:
[image: Bad Job]

Whereas the manual trigger does correctly load the env:
[image]

We have tried multiple different "solutions" ranging from resetting our repository secrets to explicitly instantiating the env at the job level (in addition to the workflow level). The result has been the same every time.

Comment: Is there any yaml file we can have a look at ?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out after getting deep into the GitHub documentation. The issue is reusable workflows do not have access to secrets by default. You have to explicitly require them in the called workflow or pass it via `inherit` in the caller workflow. The `inherit` keyword seems to be a more recent addition, hence why it was so difficult to find.